# HTML &nbsp; not occupying vertical space

Tags: html, css

I want my `&nbsp;` to occupy the vertical space of its parent DIV. It's being rendered in the markup but it doesn't occupy the vertical space.

I've tried removing the *white-space:nowrap* style on the DIV. I also tried googlearching but came up empty because everything was about DIVs, special chars and tables.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: `&nbsp;` is a space, maybe you;re looking for `&#10;` (line-feed)? Or im getting it wrong..

Comment: Have you tried to define a `line-height` ? or use a `display:table;` on your `div` ? Plus, could give your code ? I can't get why you want your `&nbsp;` to occupy the height. :)
https://jsfiddle.net/vephjvtu/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post your CSS so we can see what is going wrong. Look at this simple JSFiddle, with only **background-color** it renders as you want :)

```css
div {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: In fact you made me realize that I didn't have a problem, so +1 and accepted.